# winforms - c++ - invoke method

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2019, invoke

i'm trying to implement an invoke method for updateing an textbox from another thread.

to do so, i followed some instructions/tutorials on the internet, but without success:

this is where my main form initialize ,called MyForm.cpp:

```
Calc::MyForm::MyForm(){

InitializeComponent();

System::Threading::Thread ^plsInvoke = gcnew Thread(this, &Calc::initatePls);
//Thread = thread
plsInvoke->Start();
}
```

the function I want to thread is located in pls.cpp, and called initatePls.

```
void Calc::initatePls()

{
hCommPLS = connectCom(6, 115200);   
sendPls();
}
```

the error i'm reciving:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'System::Threading::Thread::Thread(const System::Threading::Thread %)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'System::Threading::ThreadStart ^'   Calc    C:\Users\david\OneDrive*******\Calc\MyForm.cpp 111

the goal, as I said, update the textbox with global variable located in pls.cpp.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include `namespace System` and `namespace System::Threading`, or to write the whole namespace each time `System::Threading::Thread`.

You can also create a `gcnew ThreadStart`  in your `gcnew Thread` to immediatly start the Thread so you can remove `threadName->Start();`

**Example:**

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

void exampleFunction() {
    Thread^ thread1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Calc::initatePls));
}
```